# How to check the value of th:utext in thymeleaf page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I send the HTML tags from controller to Thymeleaf page, and then I show the HTML tags in the Thymeleaf pages as shown below

```
<div tags="remove">
    <div id="accordian" th:utext="${strMenu}"></div>
</div>
```

But I want to check the value of `strMenu` is null or not in the Thymeleaf page.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Elvis operator `?` which evaluates the expression only if it is not `null`. The source in the Thymeleaf section [4.11 Default expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator).

```
<div id="accordian" th:utext="${strMenu != null}? ${strMenu} : 'default value' "></div>
```

Or

```
<div id="accordian" th:utext="${strMenu?}"></div>
```